# One server needs to post data to another server by means of AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, server

I am having a local website which needs to post some data to another server in the internet. While it was ok to post these http requests while remaining in the same domain and in the same machine, it is not responding to such requests when I am trying to post some data from one machine to another.

If I have the following code:

```
<form name="formOne" id="formOne" method="post" 
action="http://someUrl.com/acceptRequest.php">
<input .... />
<input .... />
<input name="submitButton" id="submitButton" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Manually clicking on the submit button is allowing me to post the matter contained in the form to be posted to the third party website, AJAX through jQuery is not allowing the automation of the same thing via

```
$.post ("http://someUrl.com/acceptRequest.php", 
{data:data}, 
function(resultSet) { ... }, 
"html");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX cross domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

Comment: Is your Ajax code triggered when submit button clicked? Based on the code it simply just coded and not being called or trigger to any element.